# MySQL: Slow to copy data from many tables to new structure

Tags: mysql, database, migration

Scenario: I had to redesign an entire database, requiring new tables, for a migration from one version of software to another. This is only 2-3GB worth of data.

I've created the migration script with many INSERT INTO... SELECT transactions.

It takes roughly 3-4 hours to migrate on a single-disk, whereas on a raid-5 setup, I fear it is going to take longer when I take it to production.

My question is, is there a quicker way to do this in MySQL, or am I just S.O.L and have to bite the bullet on this? I think it might take more than 1-2 days of production downtime, which is difficult to do in this situation.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/31865

Comment: Are you saying just changing the max_allowed_packet size would help?

Comment: all sorts of things to consider, like no indexes, no fks (until after-the-fact), doing batch inserts not one row at a time, doing bulk insert, loading with load table, not output scripts generated from that tool. You need to explore other options in that realm versus just running an .sql file  These things need to be explored and tested in unit testing of devops. Can't be answered in one broad brush stroke in a little box down here. Tinker

Comment: as for me, I wouldn't do any of that. I would bring the files over. And hook em in. Not a single insert statement. Voila